# Access python for loop values

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I'm experimenting a bit with Python and am trying to build a scraper. Code I already have is printed below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "http://www.grammy.com/nominees/search"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "view-content"})

f = csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Year", "Category", "Title", "Winner"])

for item in g_data:
  for year in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-year"}):
    year = year.contents[0]

  for category in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-category-code"}):
    category = category.contents[0]

  for title in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-field-nominee-work"}):
    title = title.contents[0]

  for winner in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-field-nominee-extended"}):
    winner = winner.contents[0]

f.writerow([year, category, title, winner])
```

For some reason the CSV file only has 1 row, a random one. How will I be able to access all these values outside of its `for` scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only that your last `writerow()` is not indented properly (it should be under the loop body). Also, you need to iterate over `tr` elements (representing each row in the desired `table` containing the data), get the `td` elements for each `tr` found in the loop.

I would also avoid checking `class` attribute values of `td` elements in the loop and would just get them by index - in other words, find all `td` elements for every `tr` and get the `text`.

Fixed and improved version (just 2 lines of code):

```
for item in soup.select("div.view-content table tr")[1:]:
    f.writerow([td.get_text(strip=True).encode("utf-8") for td in item.find_all("td")])
```

The contents of the `file.csv` after running the code:

```
Year,Category,Title,Winner
2014,Record Of The Year,Stay With Me (Darkchild Version),"Sam Smith, artist. Steve Fitzmaurice, Rodney Jerkins & Jimmy Napes, producers. Matthew Champlin, Steve Fitzmaurice, Jimmy Napes & Steve Price, engineers/mixers. Tom Coyne, mastering engineer."
2014,Album Of The Year,Morning Phase,"Beck Hansen, producer; Tom Elmhirst, David Greenbaum, Cole Marsden Greif-Neill, Florian Lagatta, Robbie Nelson, Darrell Thorp, Cassidy Turbin & Joe Visciano, engineers/mixers; Bob Ludwig, mastering engineer."
2014,Song Of The Year,Stay With Me (Darkchild Version),"James Napier, William Phillips &Sam Smith, songwriters."
...
2014,Best Rap Song,I,"K. Duckworth, Ronald Isley & C. Smith, songwriters."
2014,Best Rap Album,The Marshall Mathers LP2,"Eminem, artist. Tony Campana, Joe Strange & Mike Strange, engineers/mixers."
```

Comment: What's te best approach to split these fields into separate columns?

Comment: @BobWassermann could you elaborate what do you mean by "split these fields into separate columns"?

Comment: Right now Python puts all the data into one columns, which looks like "2014,Best Country Solo Performance,Something In The Water,"Carrie Underwood, artist."", 2014, best country solo..., etc need to be in separate columns. TLDR; Each ``,`` should open a new column

Comment: Got it. Delimiter ';' fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your write call is outside of your loop, so you're only writing one line (the last one). Indent it, and it should work as expected:

```
for item in g_data:
  for year in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-year"}):
    year = year.contents[0]

  for category in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-category-code"}):
    category = category.contents[0]

  for title in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-field-nominee-work"}):
    title = title.contents[0]

  for winner in item.find_all("td", {"class": "views-field-field-nominee-extended"}):
    winner = winner.contents[0]

  f.writerow([year, category, title, winner])
```

In case you are new to Python, code blocks are defined by indentation.

Comment: Yes, but how can I define "undefined" strings. For instance: in the first ``for loop``, the other values aren't defined yet